# Flex Air: Read "ActionScript object" from file then cast?

Tags: apache-flex, object, air

It is quite simple to do it, you write the object down to file, then you read it:

- http://corlan.org/2008/09/02/storing-data-locally-in-air/
- http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Storing_ActionScript_Objects_in_the_Encrypted_Loca-10563.html

My questions are

1. why when we put [RemoteClass(alias="foo.Bar")] into VO, it can be
   cast automatically (otherwise the type of the deserialized object is
   Generic Object with correct properties data inside it)?
2. Is there another way to achieve it without RemoteClass tag? (Using metadata tag is preference)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The answer is in the [page](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Storing_ActionScript_Objects_in_the_Encrypted_Loca-10563.html) you linked to:

   > Note that the alias is a key that is stored with the class instance
   >   and links the class definition with the specific object that is stored
   >   in the ByteArray when an instance of that object is serialized. This
   >   key can be any unique string identifying this class, but convention is
   >   to use the fully normalized package and class name.

   That's why you get a generic object if you omit the alias - the deserialization method does not know what to do with the data, unless you specify to which class the values should be mapped.
2. Yes, there is: [`registerClassAlias()`](http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/08/actionscript-3-serializing-classes-using-registerclassalias/) does the same thing. But the metadata tag is much prettier to read ;)

Comment: Thank you. I think you answered the question, though we decide to use data model-driven from Adobe which generate all sqlLite DAO code. No need to serialize/deserialize things any more